# How native method registered in ndk sample hello-jni(It does not looks like static register or dynamic register)

Tags: java-native-interface

I am little puzzled by this sample, I have know that native methods have two way to register in JNI. If you use a static one, you need to generate signature, something like ***.h, and include it in you native file. And apparently, hello-jni do not use dynamic one. code look like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h> 

/* This is a trivial JNI example where we use a native method
 * to return a new VM String. See the corresponding Java source
 * file located at:
 *
 *   apps/samples/hello-jni/project/src/com/example/hellojni/HelloJni.java
 */
jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

and java

```
public native String  stringFromJNI();
```

I have searched in google, and found some cue about JVM, I know very little about JVM, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The C code is using a function declaration that could be generated by something like:

```
javah -classpath apps/samples/hello-jni/project/src com.example.hellojni.HelloJni
```

`javah` processes the bytecode file (HelloJni.class) compiled from HelloJni.java to extract methods declared with `native` into C function prototypes. The implementation is defining one of those:

```
jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv*, jobject);
```

It presumably is doing this without bothering to the declare the function first nor using the header generated by `javah`. In C, that's generally allowed. Perhaps they copied, pasted and edited the output of `javah`, though you could learn to do what `javah` does in your head.

**UPDATE:** 
Also, in C, function declarations don't need named parameters. In the implementation, you have to give a name for each parameter that is used. So, the following are possible:

```
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    // implementation
}
```

Or, since the second argument is not used by the implementation:

```
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject )
{
    // implementation
}
```

### Linking

The dynamic linking occurs when some Java code calls `system.loadLibrary("name")`. The typical location for such a call is in a static initializer block of each class that declares `native` methods implemented by the library:

```
public class HelloJni
{
   static { system.loadLibrary("hellojni"); }
   ...
}
```

The JVM then searches for a shared library (.so or .dll) on the search path in the property `java.library.path`. It tries various platform-dependent prefixes ("lib") and suffixes (".so", ".dll") to find the file. If it can't find any such file, it throws an exception.

Independently, when a call is made to a function declared with `native`, the JVM searches the loaded libraries for an exported function that matches the name of the function. The matching is done per the JNI function naming convention used by `javah` and C function mangling rules used by the C compiler/linker. If it can't find such a function, it throws an exception. It should all work out if you include jni.h and headers produced by `javah`.

---

Note: Be very careful with `NewStringUTF`. It takes a 0-terminated, Unicode string with a modified UTF-8 encoding. The example relies on the limited subset of characters used in the string, the source file encoding and the compiler's construction of the char array from the literal just happening to create a byte sequence that is identical to the modified UTF-8 encoding of the string.

If you can use C++11 instead of C, `NewString` works very nicely with a `std::u16string` holding UTF-16 code units. (UTF-16 code units are what Java uses internally.)

Comment: thx for the answer, but I still confused by how native and java combine in this case. As you know, if I use javah, I get this"JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);" It looks like difference with the sample. And I need include head file in C. So how jvm found native method in this case.